# AM protocol for 2 distinct objects

Tags: protocol-design

Prover is going to convince verifier that 2 objects are distinct, do you know any Arthur-Merlin protocol for this problem?

Comment: Does the parties have a [commitment](http://crypto.cs.uiuc.edu/wiki/index.php/Commitment_scheme) to each object? $\:$ If no, what specifies the objects? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: To clarify, consider a blind person who is going to buy 2 dolls which are same except in colors.How the salesperson can convince the blind that their colors are diferent.

Comment: The zero knowledge proof is as follows.the blind randomly choses one of them and asks salesperson(prover) to determine the object, and reoeats this algorithm!

Comment: objects $\mapsto$ [orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers) $\:$ ? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: What you mean,orbits?

Comment: I mean what I linked to. $\;$

Comment: I didn't get you, but anyway thank you

Comment: Graph non isomorphism could be related. Goldreich, Micali, Wigderson "Proofs that yield nothing but their validity and a methodology of cryptographic protocol design"

Comment: I know an Artur-Merlin proof for graph noniso but I cant present an Artur-Merlin proof for 2distinct objects which I discribed above!!!